# Fixed layout HTML table distorted when rendered into mpdf

Tags: php, html, layout, mpdf

Although the HTML is generated in a fixed static layout with its own CSS, 
the HTML gets distorted if rendered with mpdf into a pdf-file.

```
    $mpdf = new Mpdf([
        'mode' => 'utf-8',
        'format' => [460, 405], // should be big enough to fit
        'orientation' => 'P',
    ]);


    $mpdf->AddPageByArray([
        'margin-left' => 0,
        'margin-right' => 0,
        'margin-top' => 0,
        'margin-bottom' => 0,
    ]);

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($data);
    $mpdf->Output($filename . '_EZ.pdf', 'I');
```

The HTML is generated based on the following template

https://github.com/sprain/php-swiss-qr-bill/blob/master/src/PaymentPart/Output/HtmlOutput/Template/PaymentPartTemplate.php

What causes this behavior in mpdf?

[image: PDF Output with Mpdf]

[image: HTML Output]

Comment: please do not post personal information in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Well mpdf is very specific about what css tags you can use and what html tags to use where. I recommend going [through the manual](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/introduction.html). [But the biggest problem I see is using divisions in the table](https://mpdf.github.io/tables/tables.html). Mpdf doesn't support that. Look at supported tags in [the documentation.](https://mpdf.github.io/html-support/html-tags.html)

I recommend rewriting the entire template read through the docs and first test only half of your design etc.

But to give you a couple of pointers that helped me.

1. In a table cell:
   Always use spans and break to get the desired output.

```
<span class="some-class">Value</span></br>
<span class="some-class">Line2</span></br>
```

2. If aligning items differently in a table use attribute align.
3. Use inline css when possible.
4. Go step by step figure out just a part of your layout and then you should be able to figure out the rest.
5. Prepare yourself to rewrite the entire template 2 - 4 times at least.

Comment: Rewriting the entire template - yes a good idea thanks, and quite not that hard. -- Somehow didn't think about that

Comment: I found it a bit cumbersome to get the exact design I wanted.